# How to understand the conversation between the people in the hellfire and those in paradise in the qur'an?

Tags: quran, tafseer, jannah, jahannam

In the qur'an we find a couple of verses which quote conversations between the people in Jahnnam أصحاب النار and those in al-Jannah أصحاب الجنة‎  like:

- > And the companions of Paradise will call out to the companions of the Fire, "We have already found what our Lord promised us to be true. Have you found what your Lord promised to be true?" They will say, "Yes." Then an announcer will announce among them, "The curse of Allah shall be upon the wrongdoers." ([7:44](https://legacy.quran.com/7/44))
- > And the companions of the Fire will call to the companions of Paradise, "Pour upon us some water or from whatever Allah has provided you." They will say, "Indeed, Allah has forbidden them both to the disbelievers." ([7:50](https://legacy.quran.com/7/50))
- > And he will look and see him in the midst of the Hellfire. (55)
  >   He will say, "By Allah , you almost ruined me. (56)
  >   If not for the favor of my Lord, I would have been of those brought in [to Hell]. ([37:55-57](https://legacy.quran.com/37/55-57))

I wonder how one should interpret these verses and the conversation:
Will people in Jannah (Paradise) and the people in Jahanm (Hellfire) be able to communicate with each other?
Or how else is the quotation of the conversation between both in the qur'an to be interpreted?

Comment: Other than that they can communicate with each other, I don't see how else you can interpret it. Unless you mean to say metaphorical which doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: @TheZ yeah I was wondering if it was to be taken metaphorical or as an example...

Answer (score 1):

It has to be taken literally because the descriptions of these conversations are in the same passages as the descriptions of Paradise and Hell without any identifying separations between them.

So, taking these conversations as metaphorical would not make sense when the rest of the passage is literal.

For example, in this passage, they are literally in the same sentence:

> except the People of the Right Hand. [They will be] in gardens, questioning concerning the guilty: ‘What drew you into Hell?’ (74:39-42)

In this case, the "[They will be] in gardens" is clearly literal hence the rest of the sentence must be so as well.

So, the conclusion has to be that the people of Paradise and Hell have some way of communication, the conversations of which are reported about in the Quran

Comment: And how you explain the separation between both quoted in "And between them will be a partition ..."[7:46](https://legacy.quran.com/7/46) and [57:13](https://legacy.quran.com/57/13).

Comment: @Medi1Saif . According to Ibn Kathir, "After Allah mentioned that the people of Paradise will address the people of the Fire, He stated that there is a barrier between Paradise and the Fire, which prevents the people of the Fire from reaching Paradise." Hence, the wall is one that prevents them from crossing out of the Fire, but not one that obstructs view or sound.